# Cylinder meshes and boundaries

Tags: mesh

Maybe i am just missing something.

(Eevee, Blender 2.9)
I have a cylinder and I wish to add 2 meshes to and cut a shape from the side.

I select cylinder object and then use Ctrl+R in edit mode to create an upper segment.
I highlight all faces of the upper segment and apply one material - pink.
I highlight all the remaining lower faces and apply second material - grey.

I add smooth shading, edge split and subsurface division (catmuli) - then the mesh material (pink) jumps and extends beyond the mesh bounds.

If i click "on cage" option in subsurf then the mesh material extends to the full size of material - but not to the original height of the mesh cut.

Then i add a rectangle mesh and perform a "knife project" on them to cut shape out of side of cylinder. Doing this displaces the entire material.

In the attached blend file there are 3 cylinders

Cylinder 1 - the original size of material applied to top segment, no modifiers

Cylinder 2 - the new size of pink material, after applying modifiers.

Cylinder 3 - the deformed material from the knife project

Why does this material displacement happen? Why the deform on knife project?

Thanks in advance.
U.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you rephrase the title and the body of your question so it is more clear what you are asking ? As it stands I feel it's very difficult to pinpoint what exactly you want. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the *Subdivision modifier*.
It interpolates the spacing between edges, and the subdivided geometry is slightly moved.

The same thing is causing the distortion when adding cuts with *knife-project*. You're effectivelly adding loopcuts, which limits the stretching.

These are your options:

1. Add a crease to the edge
2. Make the geometry evenly spaced on the object
3. Add a loopcut on both sides of the edge
4. Split the edge using *Edge split modifier*

[image]

Comment: Bad ass man, thanks!